# Создать список столбцов со значениями "yes" или "no" из датафрейма pandas

Tags: python, строки, pandas, dataframe

Мне надо заменить все значения `yes/no` на `1/0` в датафрейме pandas. Как это сделать я знаю, но вот для начала я хотел бы создать список из этих столбцов, но никак идеи в голову не приходят.

Comment: пример нужен. То, что есть и то, что нужно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так. Eсли у вас строковые только эти колонки, то дополнительная проверка с `any` не нужна, тем более я её явно не оптимально как-то написал.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'int': [1, 2, 3], 'obj1': ['yes', 'no', 'yes'], 'obj2': ['no', 'yes', 'no'], 'obj3': ['n', 'y', 'n']})

obj_columns = df.columns[df.dtypes == 'object'].to_list()
for col in obj_columns:
    if any(df[col].str.contains(x).any() for x in ('yes','no')):
        df[col] = df[col].map({'yes': 1, 'no': 0})
```

На выходе:

```
  int obj1  obj2 obj3
0   1    1     0    n
1   2    0     1    y
2   3    1     0    n
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, оказывается всё проще чем я думал)

Comment: @A4eVsmisle В `Pandas` вообще всё просто, если знать как и что делать :)

Answer (score 2):

Можно сначала получить список строковых столбцов, а после заменить во всех строковых столбцах `yes` -> `1`, `no` -> `0`:

```
cols = df.columns[df.dtypes.eq("object")]
df.loc[:, cols] = df[cols].replace({'yes': 1, 'no': 0})
```

результат:

```
In [8]: df
Out[8]:
   int  obj1  obj2 obj3
0    1     1     0    n
1    2     0     1    y
2    3     1     0    n
```

PS пример данных я позаимствовал из ответа уважаемого @CrazyElf :)

Comment: Так и знал, что можно через `.loc` всё же сделать, без цикла, но что-то у меня сходу не заработало )